# [iOS][Android] AppStore and publication: can the publication be rejected because of a webview?

Tags: android, ios, store, appstore-approval

I'm a mobile developer and I have a client that own an hairdressing business. He had a mobile app that allowed to schedule appointments, but this app is no longer maintained. Since some months, he shared an URL that allow customers to schedule appointments.

He would like to create a new mobile app that will contain basic informations  and a web view that will use the URL dedicated to the appointments.

I think it could be something like this:

- 1 tab for a the business presentation (address, phone number, map, ...)
- 1 tab for news (holidays, ...)
- 1 tab for their offers
- 1 tab that will contain the webview

***I don't know if this could be a problem for Apple or Google regarding the Store publication?***

Comment: you will have to ask each store, we won't be able to help you here because it's a policy related to the store

Answer (score 0):

I am more of an Android developer so I can answer regarding Android :) Google doesn't have any restriction if you use just web views within the application, you just need to ensure you have SSL certificate pinning & clear text traffic restricted enabled else there are chancels of getting rejected.

For Apple, I think they would reject if you just use webviews but I am not absolutely sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Apple give you all the app store review guidelines. A quick google will give you the answer: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality
> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store.

So no, apple will not allow an app that simply wraps a website. There also isn't any value in all the effort needed to build this, because users can just access the same content on a browser.

Google play store doesn't have any such restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As I explained, the app will contain other features, like a quick business presentation (address, phone number, map,...), some new related to the business, and a list of the business offers. In my idea, the app will contain 4 tabs: the business presentation, the news, the offers and the webview allowing to schedule appointments.

Comment: @Gold.strike you didn't mention any of that in your question. Again pointing back to apples review guidelines and the snippet I posted. Apples requirement is that you add other content to the app and not just the website. Sounds pretty clear that this requirement is met. Personally i'd look into seeing if his website is using an API that you can use instead of embedding the website. Embedding the site will work, but will be a shitty experience for users